# Unselect all records of same customer if a condition met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two data tables:

Table KHACHHANG:

```
MAKH    TENKH              DIACHI       DT       EMAIL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
KH01    NGUYEN THI BE      TAN BINH     8457895  bnt@yahoo.com
KH02    LE HOANG NAM       BINH CHANH   9878987  namlehoang @abc.com.vn
KH03    TRAN THI CHIEU     TAN BINH     8457895 
KH04    MAI THI QUE ANH    BINH CHANH       
KH05    LE VAN SANG        QUAN 10               sanglv@hcm.vnn.vn
KH06    TRAN HOANG KHAI    TAN BINH     8457897
```

Table HOADON:

```
MAHD    NGAY        MAKH
------------------------
HD001   12/05/2000  KH01
HD002   25/05/2000  KH02
HD003   25/05/2000  KH01
HD004   25/05/2000  KH04
HD005   26/05/2000  KH04
HD006   02/06/2000  KH03
HD007   22/06/2000  KH04
HD008   25/06/2000  KH03
HD009   15/08/2000  KH04
HD010   30/09/2000  KH01
```

I want to list all customers that did not place order in June 2000. This is my code:

```
select distinct KHACHHANG.MAKH, DIACHI, DT
    from KHACHHANG
    left join HOADON
    on HOADON.MAKH = KHACHHANG.MAKH
    where MONTH(HOADON.NGAY)<>6 and YEAR(HOADON.NGAY)=2000
        or KHACHHANG.MAKH not in (select MAKH from HOADON)
```

But the result was:

```
MAKH  DIACHI                                             DT
----- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
KH01  TAN BINH                                           8457895
KH02  BINH CHANH                                         9878987
KH04  BINH CHANH                                         NULL
KH05  QUAN 10                                            NULL
KH06  TAN BINH                                           8457897
```

The record of Customer ID **KH04** should not appear in the result because he bought something on **22/06/2000**.
So how can I remove the KH04 from the result ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `not exists`:

```
select k.*
from KHACHHANG k
where not exists (
  select 1 from HOADON
  where makh = k.makh and MONTH(ngay) = 6 and YEAR(ngay)=2000  
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked. But what's the role of "select 1" there?

Comment: `select 1..` is there to ensure that a row exists. It could be `select *..` or `select 0` or `select anycolumn..`, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want `not exists`:

```
select k.*
from KHACHHANG k
where not exists (select 1
                  from HOADON h
                  where h.MAKH = k.MAKH and
                        h.ngay >= '2000-06-01' and
                        h.ngay < '2000-07-01'
                 );
```

I would recommend an index on `HOADON(MAKH, NGAY)`.

Note that I changed the date comparisons.  This makes them more amenable to using an index.

Comment: Thanks. The date was in the original data table so i copied them without changing.